# simplest (rectangular) drop shadow for an UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiview, shadow

I've seen lots of snippets that either: are too complicated for something as simple as a drop shadow, requiring subclassing UIView and using quartz2d calls, or I can't get them to work.

I just want to do this on a view I'm adding as a subview to another one (the subview is taken from another viewController I'm just allocating - I know that's probably not nice but oh well), no IB or anything. what's the simplest / most accepted way to go about it? would it be different if I want it to work on iOS 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's as easy as importing `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and using a similar snippet as below:

```
self.viewAboutContainer.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.viewAboutContainer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
self.viewAboutContainer.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
self.viewAboutContainer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);    
self.viewAboutContainer.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.viewAboutContainer.bounds].CGPath;
```

Comment: Also make sure that self.viewAboutContainer.clipsToBounds = NO. Otherwise, the shadow will fall outside of the view and be clipped.

Comment: @Brayden i had resoled the perfomence issue using "[myview.layer setShadowPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myview.bounds].CGPath];". Shadow and corner radious is working fine in Portrait mode with smooth scrolling. but my app is supported in both mode and when i change the orientation shadow not working properly(shadow display according to fram of Portrait View) .so any idea how to resolved this ?

Comment: @VictorEngel viewAboutContainer is a name of _any_ UIView or anything that inherits UIView (i.e. UIImageView).  The name is just a placeholder.

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty I was scratching my head for the day long....but finally you made my day :)

Comment: @KenM.Haggerty, setting `clipsToBounds = NO` only needs if your view (on which you wants to apply shadow) is a sub view of other view.

Comment: @Coder, I'm not sure, but you may need to reapply shadow after your app would rotate.